# Cannot use object of type stdClass as array error in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5.4

I am using Laravel 5.4 when I get the image using id with map function and return the image directory I got this error

This is function inside controller

```
 $shipping = DB::table('shipping')
            ->select('shipping.id','products.name','shipping.is_return','shipping.pro_id as pid','shipping.tracking_url')
            ->join('products','shipping.pro_id','=','products.id')
            ->orderBy('shipping.id', 'desc')
            ->limit('5')->get();

        $shipping->map(function ($ship) {
           $directory = 'uploads/products/images/'.$ship->pid;
           if (is_dir($directory)) {
            $files = scandir ($directory);
            $img_file = $directory.'/'.$files[2];
            $ship->front_img = $img_file;
            print_r($ship['front_img']);exit;
           }           
         });
```

When I try to print the output it shows the error.

Comment: Do `$ship->front_img` instead

Comment: tried that also...the same error occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get value using array but `$ship` is object

```
$shipping = DB::table('shipping')->select('shipping.id','products.name','shipping.is_return','shipping.pro_id as pid','shipping.tracking_url')
            ->join('products','shipping.pro_id','=','products.id')
            ->orderBy('shipping.id', 'desc')
            ->limit('5')->get();

        $shipping->map(function ($ship) {
           $directory = 'uploads/products/images/'.$ship->pid;
           if (is_dir($directory)) {
            $files = scandir ($directory);
            $img_file = $directory.'/'.$files[2];
            $ship->front_img = $img_file;
            print_r($ship->front_img);exit; //change here
           }           
         });
```